# Update textfield value with ajax data using angular js

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular js directives for bootstrap. What i am trying for is to create an edit form on bootstrap modal when user clicks on edit button from list of items. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Edit Template</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="form" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="span4" ng-class="smClass" ng-show="etemplate.status">{{etemplate.status}}</div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="etemplateName">Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input class="input-xlarge" id="etemplateName" ng-model="eTemplate.name" maxlength="150" type="text" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="etemplateDesc">Description</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea id="templateDesc" id="etemplateDesc" ng-model="eTemplate.desc"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="center">
                      <input type="text" style="display:none;" ng-model="eTemplate.id" value="{{eTemplate.id}}" required />
                      <button type="button" ng-click="update(eTemplate)" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || isUnchanged(eTemplate)">Submit</button>
                      <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
controller('TemplateController', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', function($scope, $http, $modal) {
    var tmpId = '';
    $scope.openEdit = function(id) {
        tmpId = id;
        var editTmpModalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'editTemplateContent.html',
            controller: 'ETModalInstance'
        });

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: adminBaseUrl+'/get_template/',
            params: {'id': tmpId}
            }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.$broadcast('EditTemplateDataReached', data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            });
    }
}]).

controller('ETModalInstance', ['$scope', '$http', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $http, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.emaster = {};
    $scope.smClass = '';
    $scope.eTemplate = {};

    $scope.$on('EditTemplateDataReached', function(data) {
        $scope.eTemplate = data;
        $scope.$apply();
    });

    $scope.isUnchanged = function(eTemplate) {
        return angular.equals(eTemplate, $scope.master);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.update = function(eTemplate) {
        var strng = $.param(eTemplate);
    };
}]).
```

My work around for achieving this is when user clicks on edit button id of selected item is passed in my controller which sends an ajax request to server and then fill the fields with respective values. However my fields are not populated when ajax data is returned.

Comment: What's your controller for first segment of code?

Comment: TemplateController is the controller which sends an ajax request to server. broadcast the value to ETModalInstance controller.

Comment: Yes but each controller has a different scope, so which controller does the HTML template belong to? Also, side note - `ng-model="eTemplate.id" value="{{eTemplate.id}}"` you do not need `value` set here since ng-model does 2 way data binding to the value attribute for you.

Comment: HTML template belongs to Template controller.

Comment: yeah i know ng-model does two way binding but its not working here. I have removed the value attribute from above fields but couldnt noticed here

Comment: Is this html currently opening in a modal dialog?

Comment: Is certain data being filled in and not other data?

Comment: Yeah modal dialog is opening fine. You are confusing because the ng-controller directive is written in the above element which i didnt posted here because there is no need for that. Problem that i am facing is my textfields are not populated when ajax response is recieved

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: Angular version 1.2.3 and angular directive for bootstrap version is 0.7.0

Comment: Try `ng-model="$parent.eTemplate.desc"`. Angular bootstrap's modal service might add a child scope to your modal.

Comment: Couldn't tell you. Could you make a jsfiddle with some more complete code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem in my code i was using $scope for broadcasting and catching the data whereas i have to use $rootScope.

Wrong:

```
$scope.$broadcast('EditTemplateDataReached', data);
$scope.$on('EditTemplateDataReached', function(data) {
        $scope.eTemplate = data;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
```

Correct:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('EditTemplateDataReached', data);
$rootScope.$on('EditTemplateDataReached', function(e, data) {
        $scope.eTemplate = data;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
```